oracle query performance issue with date field in join condition
Following oracle SQL query with 4 million records in Table A and 47 million records in Table B, having performance issue. if i remove Date condition at the end it runs faster. please provide suggestions?
select a.* 
from TBL_ZIP_CD A
INNER JOIN TBL_ZIP4_PLUS_CD B ON A.ZIPCD = B.ZIP_CD
   AND (B.EFCT_DT BETWEEN A.EFCT_DT and A.EXPR_DT
        AND B.EXPR_DT BETWEEN A.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT)
    OR (A.EFCT_DT BETWEN B.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT
        AND A.EXPR_DT BETWEEN B.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT)


AND has higher precedence than OR, your query is the same as:
SELECT a.*
FROM   TBL_ZIP_CD A
       INNER JOIN TBL_ZIP4_PLUS_CD B
       ON (
              A.ZIPCD = B.ZIP_CD
          AND B.EFCT_DT BETWEEN A.EFCT_DT and A.EXPR_DT
          AND B.EXPR_DT BETWEEN A.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT
                               -- Should this ^^ be A.EXPR_DT?
          )
          OR
          (
              A.EFCT_DT BETWEEN B.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT
          AND A.EXPR_DT BETWEEN B.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT
          )

You are not checking A.ZIPCD = B.ZIP_CD with the second part of the OR and this probably means you are matching too many rows.

What you probably want is:
SELECT a.*
FROM   TBL_ZIP_CD A
       INNER JOIN TBL_ZIP4_PLUS_CD B
       ON (   A.ZIPCD = B.ZIP_CD
          AND (
                 (
                     B.EFCT_DT BETWEEN A.EFCT_DT and A.EXPR_DT
                 AND B.EXPR_DT BETWEEN A.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT
                                      -- Should this ^^ be A.EXPR_DT?
                 )
              OR (
                     A.EFCT_DT BETWEEN B.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT
                 AND A.EXPR_DT BETWEEN B.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT
                 )
              )
          )

Or maybe (depending on whether you are expecting B to match multiple rows and do not want duplicates in A to appear if there are multiple matches):
SELECT *
FROM   TBL_ZIP_CD A
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   TBL_ZIP4_PLUS_CD B
         WHERE  A.ZIPCD = B.ZIP_CD
         AND    (
                   (
                       B.EFCT_DT BETWEEN A.EFCT_DT and A.EXPR_DT
                   AND B.EXPR_DT BETWEEN A.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT
                                        -- Should this ^^ be A.EXPR_DT?
                   )
                OR (
                       A.EFCT_DT BETWEEN B.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT
                   AND A.EXPR_DT BETWEEN B.EFCT_DT and B.EXPR_DT
                   )
                )
       )


thanks for the help, i will try that and update how it goes.
